# tr:validateDateTimeRange not working in Trinidad 1.0.13

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I am using Trinidad 1.0.13 and below is the code I have used

```
<tr:inputDate id="defaultDateCS" maximumLength="10" simple="true"
    disabled= "#{pymtAddBackingBean.pymtAddModelBean.proActiveReageFlag}"
    value="#{pymtAddBackingBean.defaultDate}" styleClass="hi90t_center"
    shortDesc="Default Date Calendar Control">
    <tr:validateDateTimeRange id="custServiceAgentDateRestriction"
    maximum="#{pymtAddBackingBean.custServiceDefaultDate}" 
    minimum="#{pymtAddBackingBean.custServiceDefaultDate}"></tr:validateDateTimeRange></tr:inputDate>
```

But when I start the application I get the below warning message when I render the page

> /pages/test.jspx @520,67 id="custServiceAgentDateRestriction"
>        Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type
>        org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.validator.DateTimeRangeValidator

Is this meaning Trinidad 1.0.13 will not support this tag? If so could you please suggest me some other alternative: My requirement is the trinidad date picker should show only one date as enabled (may be only current date) and if user enters a date manually then that should be validated for current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `id` attribute as it's not supported by `<tr:validateDateTimeRange>`.

Please check the [documentation on `<tr:validateDateTimeRange>`](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_validateDateTimeRange.html) for supported attributes.

I also noticed that you use the same dates for minimum and maximum. That's probably not right.